# how do I install pcd_viewer?

Tags: ros, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't have pcd_viewer installed
I have ROS electric
please tell me how do I install pcd viewer
OR how can I see my PCD file alternately

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29982/how-do-i-install-pcd_viewer?/) by [ElCid](https://answers.ros.org/users/1929/elcid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have the perception_pcl stack installed? pcd_viewer is included with the pcl package in pcl/bin.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2012-03-19**:
Should be easy to do with: `rosrun pcl pcd_viewer YOUR_FILE.pcd` on a default Electric install